Как правильно записать и понять предложение?
Тонуть(?) так тонуть, кричать(?) так кричать.
Какой знак и почему можно здесь поставить? Также какой смысл в этом предложении и о какой ситуации может идти речь?
Дополнение:  Плывущему — море
Плывущему — море,
Где рифы и мели.
Тонуть — так тонуть, виват!
И разве кто спорит.
В грядущее горе
Гребущий не верит.
Он проклял свой путь назад.
Что ж, вольному — воля.


Русский GPT 5
В предложении «Тонуть(?) так тонуть, кричать(?) так кричать» нужно определить, какой знак препинания подходит внутри скобок — знак вопроса, восклицательный знак, точка или их отсутствие. Давайте разберемся.

Смысл выражения
Фраза построена по принципу параллельной конструкции, основанной на акценте на решительности или смирении перед обстоятельствами.

«Тонуть так тонуть» — передача идеи: если уж случилось так, что приходится тонуть, то стоит принять это без лишнего сопротивления или сожалений.
«Кричать так кричать» — противоположная идея: если уж кричать, то делать это на полную силу, не сдерживаясь.
Это риторический прием, указывающий на максимализм или принятие судьбы. Ситуация может быть эмоционально напряженной, например, героической, драматической или даже комичной. Контекст может варьироваться:
От бурного обсуждения эмоций: «Если уж проявлять чувства, то полностью».
До экстремальных жизненных ситуаций: «Если мы тонем, давайте уж идти до конца».
2. Знаки препинания внутри скобок
Вопросительный знак после глаголов тонуть и кричать ставить можно, если выражение риторическое, а говорящий размышляет или иронизирует:
«Тонуть? Так тонуть! Кричать? Так кричать!».
Этот вариант подходит, если автор передает сомнение или ироничный настрой: «А может, все-таки бороться за жизнь? Или нет?».
Восклицательный знак можно поставить, если выражение имеет оттенок эмоционального взрыва, решимости или отчаяния:
С философским спокойствием: «Тонуть так тонуть, кричать так кричать».
Каждый вариант придает тексту свою эмоциональную окраску.

Нет, выбор мне делать не приходилось .Странно, что вариант с тире GPT не предложил. А ведь т этот вариант вполне органичен здесь..

А что это за запись такая?  «Тонуть? Так тонуть, кричать? Так кричать».

О, привет! Но это к Сержу вопрос.  Наверное, это ИИ придумал) А вам песня нравится?

@Серж  Я тоже пыталась сделать выбор,  По Розенталю знак не нужен: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=104   2) при повторении слова с частицей так для усиления смысла: Пропаду так пропаду, всё равно! (Дост.); Свадьба так свадьба; я — Огудалова, я нищенства не допущу (Остр.); Вот это была косьба так косьба! (См.); Да так да, нет так нет; Не надо так не надо.  //  Какое тут усиление смысла? // Тире тогда интонационное. Может, в одном предложении (как в песне) можно и тире поставить, а в паре лучше не ставить.

Действительно, знак может быть нужен, а может и нет. Об этом и пишет ИИ.

Серж, вам Александр задал вопрос чуть выше. Ему непонятна фраза, ну и мне не очень. // По вашему ответу я могу сделать такой общий вывод: это суждение -  проявление максимализма. Но мне кажется, что это не единственный вывод. Возможны и другие толкования.

Sharon, ИИ ошибся. Корректный вариант: Тонуть? Так тонуть! Кричать? Так кричать!

От себя добавлю: я за тире. Тире здесь придает выразительность, логически подчеркивает каждую часть высказывания.

Можно предположить, что в этой теме возможны два варианта с разными смысловыми оттенками и разными знаками.

Выражение максимализма, постановка тире

Тонуть — так тонуть, кричать — так кричать.
Эта фраза из книги  К. К. Случевский
Поездки по Северу России в 1885—1886 годах
"Смелы кемлянки до безумия и нередко тонут они, даже в городском пороге, но эти безвременные жертвы не влияют ни на общий строй жизни, ни на личные характеры. Тонуть так тонуть, кричать так кричать, и кричат же кемлянки невообразимо, потому что говорить попросту в Кеми нельзя, и обыкновенная речь заглушается вечным голосом вечного порога".
Другими словами, если тонуть, то в водопаде, если кричать, то тоже от души. Отсюда следует и выбор тире, что соответствует  значению взаимообусловленности.

Повтор слов с частицей ТАК

Тонуть так тонуть, кричать так кричать.
Здесь можно увидеть надежду на удачный поворот судьбы: где наша не пропадала! Цитата из книги «Граф Монте-Кристо»: "Тонуть так тонуть, двум смертям не бывать, одной не миновать!"
Нет знака. Этот вариант с усилительным значением рассмотрен у Розенталя, пункт 4(2).
